# Pattern multiply - sed?

Tags: sed

I have these kind of rows

0 1 1

I would like to multiply it by let's say 2 or 4 to get this pattern

0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Now, I have some piece of old code, which basically does this in the case of multiplying by 5.

But I cannot convert this script to do it for example 2 or 4 times...

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Here is the code:

```
sed -e 's/\([01]\)/\1\1\1\1/7g ; s/\([01]\{2,\}\)/\1\1\1/g ; s/\b\([01]\)\b/\1\1\1\1\1/g ; s/\([01]\)\B/\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo '0 1 1' | sed -r 's/\S/& & & & &/g'
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: OK, but this is not working as the same way as mine: echo 0 1 1  | sed -r 's/\S\s*/&&&&/g' result is 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1111

Answer (score 0):

using sed repeat 4 times:

```
kent$  echo "0 1 1
1 1 0"|sed 's/[01]/& & & &/g' 

0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

with awk, you can give the times you want to repeat as parameter: e.g. say repeat 5 times:

```
kent$  echo "0 1 1
dquote> 1 1 0"|awk -v t=5 '{f=1;while(f<=NF){ n=1;while(n<=t){printf "%s ",$f;n++;}f++;} print "";}' 

0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e '0 1 1\n1 1 1 0 0' | sed "s/\S/$(echo {1..4}| sed 's/\S*/\&/g')/g"
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This provides an OTT solution but it is programmable i.e. change `4` to any value you wish to multiply by.